# how to retrieve value from Map?

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
Iterator it = request.getParameterMap().entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
```

where request is HttpServletRequest. Here is output I am getting in console

```
id = [Ljava.lang.String;@3f13bf94
title = [Ljava.lang.String;@5eea278c
dlPhone = [Ljava.lang.String;@98a6bd1
name = [Ljava.lang.String;@77736513
```

why this Ljava.lang.String???? how to get exact value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why this Ljava.lang.String?

Because each value is presumably a `String[]`, and calling `toString` directly on an array doesn't give anything particularly useful - just the normal implementation inherited from `Object`, which indicates the type and the system-generated hash code.

To get a useful representation, you could use:

```
String key = (String) pairs.getKey();
String[] values = (String[]) pairs.getValue();
System.out.println(key + " = " + Arrays.toString(values));
```

Note that generics would make this much clearer, but if `getParameterMap` is only declared to return `Map`, you don't have a lot to go on. You could perform an unchecked cast to at least reduce the amount of code - but it's not actually giving you safety at the point of the cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, String[]> map = (Map<String, String[]>) request.getParameterMap();
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `pairs.getValue()` is returning String array. Just debug and check that.

You should be iterating over `pairs.getValue()` and print each entry for your purpose here, or do 
`Arrays.toString( (String[])pairs.getValue() )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Iterator it = request.getParameterMap().keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String)it.next();
            System.out.println(key + " = " + requset.getParameter(key));
            //it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            // ??? why ???
        }
```